# How to make ads block in inappwebview flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[inappwebview](https://inappwebview.dev) has this function:

```
          contentBlockers: [
            ContentBlocker(
              trigger: ContentBlockerTrigger(
                urlFilter: '.*',
              ),
              action: ContentBlockerAction(
                  type: ContentBlockerActionType.CSS_DISPLAY_NONE,
                  selector:
                      '''.sidebar_newsletter_sign_up, .sidebar_subscribe, ......'''),
            ),
```

I also found an [easylist](https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt) which contains all the tags that need to be blocked. But I can't figure out how to put this list into a function from inappwebview? How to process it?